# Disposing ActiveX Control on a Form

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a third party ActiveX control that I am embedding in a form. The control's class implements IDisposable. My question is should I manually call the control's dispose method either in the form closing event or go into the designer and edit the form dispose method to call the control's dispose.

I understand that a form calls the dispose methods of all the controls it owns, however are there any exceptions since this is a COM control. Thanks.

PS: I am using Visual Studio 2008, .Net 3.5, Project Type: Windows Forms Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is nothing special you have to do.

Because the [`Control` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx) (from which other container controls such as [`Form`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx) inherit from) implements the [`IDisposable` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx), it should (if it follows the standard [`IDisposable` implementation guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx)) dispose of any references that it holds that implement the `IDisposable` interface.

That said, your control, assuming that it is in the controls collection exposed by the [`Controls` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx), will have it's [`IDisposable.Dispose` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) called when the window containing it is closed (as closing the window causes the window's `Dispose` method to be called).

Comment: Thanks. I got confused as I read a rule of thumb somewhere that you should always manually call dispose on classes that implement IDisposable. From your answer, can I assume that I would not have to worry about the same for controls, that implement IDisposable, and are part of a forms control collection.

Comment: @user1556110 No, if you call [`Close` method on the `Form` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx) (or simily X out the window), or dispose of a `Control`, all of the controls that it is a parent window of will be disposed of properly.

Comment: He stated that it's a COM Object so your answer is not quite right in regards to Releasing COM objects or OleAutomation objects

Comment: @DJKRAZE it's specifically an ActiveX control, which COM interop will handle correctly and is tied to the window lifetime.  Unless there is something that they're doing with the object that is unorthodox, it will be handled appropriately.

Comment: I will revert back with accepting the answer when I have confirmation

Comment: @user1556110 Confirmation of what?  Are you looking for something more, or doing the research on your own?

Comment: I understand that user1556110 but based on experience with COM this is the proper way to handle releasing of a COM Object.. 6 of one half dozen of the other...

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN Marshal.ReleaseComObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx)
In order to Release or Free a COM Object you need to use this code

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject( someComObject);
```

//this is your COM Object
    Dispose will not work on a COM Object
   for example Debug and try to Dispose your object using code like this 
   if you have an object named fs

```
((IDisposable)fs).Dispose();
```

Comment: I already release my other COM objects this way, the reason for my question was it was an ActiveX control which I added to the toolbox items from the COM tab. So I am still a little confused.